# Check if a Polly circuit breaker in a wrap is closed?

Tags: circuit-breaker, polly

I need to see is a circuit break is closed but my polices are in a policy wrap.  How can find the CircuitBreakerPolicy (one or more) in the wrap?
Is there a better way to know is any breaker is open for a given policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Polly documentation:

- The circuit-breaker [exposes its state](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Circuit-Breaker#circuit-state-for-health-reporting-polly-v40) as `breaker.CircuitState`.
- `PolicyWrap` provides a [variety of methods](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap#methods) allowing you to obtain the policies in a wrap.

For example:

```cs
var breaker = wrap.GetPolicy<CircuitBreakerPolicy>();
var state = breaker.CircuitState;
```

or:

```cs
var breaker = wrap.GetPolicy<CircuitBreakerPolicy>(p => p.PolicyKey == "SomeKey");
```

or:

```cs
IEnumerable<CircuitBreakerPolicy> breakers = wrap.GetPolicies<CircuitBreakerPolicy>();
```

---

`CircuitBreakerPolicy` (as the type to obtain) is only an example in the above.  Substitute with the specific type you need:

- `CircuitBreakerPolicy`
- `AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy`
- `AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>`

(or whatever)

Comment: thanks.  That pesky documentation.  The answer is always lurking in there.